# Request images and save them to AWS S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an array of urls to some images `images = ['url1', 'url2', ...]`.

I want to save the images to my Amazon S3 server and return an array of the new urls, pointing to S3 instead of the original urls.

I am using node.js, but I don't know which tools to use.

I guess I will have to use, for instance, `request` or `axios` and read the image as binary and save it again.

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly same few days ago. I wrote a small shell script where u can use wget/curl to download images. Or if you are good in python u can use wget package there too. python has

Also, install aws cli or s3cmd on ur server. Using these tools it is very straight forward to copy files on S3.. U can again invoke these commands from your shell script.